# Parallelization Apply to parRapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, r-sp

My data set is:

```
ll <- matrix(c(5, 6, 60, 60), ncol=2)
```

And I use the function **spDistsN1** from the library **"sp"** to obtain a distance matrix with **apply**:

```
apply(ll, 1, function(x) spDistsN1(as.matrix(ll), x, longlat = T))
```

But I want to do it with parallelization, so for that:

```
library(parallel)
ncore <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(ncore)
clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, expr = c(library(sp)))
parRapply(cl = cl, x = ll, FUN =  function(x) spDistsN1(as.matrix(ll), x, 
longlat = T))
```

It shows the following error:

*Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'll' not found*

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier alternative to using parallel's `parApply()` or `parRapply()` is to use `future_apply()` of the [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package (disclaimer: I'm the author) because global variables are automatically exported - no need to worry about `parallel::clusterExport()` etc.  Just use it as you would use `apply()`, e.g.

```
library(sp)
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess)  ## parallelize on local machine

ll <- matrix(c(5, 6, 60, 60), ncol = 2)

## Sequentially
y0 <-        apply(ll, 1, function(x) A(ll, x, longlat = TRUE))
print(y0)
#          [,1]     [,2]
# [1,]  0.00000 55.79918
# [2,] 55.79918  0.00000

## In parallel
y1 <- future_apply(ll, 1, function(x) spDistsN1(ll, x, longlat = TRUE))
print(y1)
#          [,1]     [,2]
# [1,]  0.00000 55.79918
# [2,] 55.79918  0.00000

print(identical(y1, y0))
# [1] TRUE
```

You may also find the blog post [future.apply - Parallelize Any Base R Apply Function](https://www.jottr.org/2018/06/23/future.apply_1.0.0/) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export all variables to workers. See `?parallel::clusterExport`.